# Ternary operator to include array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a nav menu with a number of links. I would like to display the links dependent on the permissions value from the export below.

The information on the links comes from the export down below. The 'access' variable is created when the user logs in and determines their role. In this scenario it's either Admin, Tenant or User.

```
    {SideNavData.map((item, index) => {
      {item.permissions === access && (
        <div>
          <Link
            className="sideNav__links"
            to={item.path}
            onClick={item.navSub && showSubnav ? showSubnav : showNav}
          >
            <div className="sideNav__icons">
              <i>{item.icon}</i>
              <span>
                {item.title}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div>
              {item.navSub && subnav ? item.iconOpened : item.navSub ? item.iconClosed : null}
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )}
     })}
    </>


export const SideNavData = [
  {
    title: 'Home',
    path: '/',
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="home" />,
    permissions: ['Admin', 'User', 'Tenant'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Tenants',
    path: '/tenants',
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="building" />,
    permissions: 'Tenant',
  },
  {
    title: 'Security',
    path: '/security',
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="shield-alt" />,
    permissions: 'User'
},
];
```

Is it possible to turn the permissions into an array (example on Home object above) and display the links accordingly. i.e all roles will see the Home link but the Tenant will see the Home and Tenant link and the User will see the Home and Security link. Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Make all of the `permissions` properties arrays and use `item.permissions.includes(access)` instead of `item.permissions === access`. I'm not sure what this question has to do with ternary expressions though...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you, that did the trick. Apologies for the incorrect title.